# Row color should change on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a question on ruby. Example, I have a table when entering fields it should check condition. For example, I have fields of `name:string`, `xyz:string` and `critical:string`. After entering fields it should check if `critical == "low"` then row color should change. Is it possible?

Any suggestions/help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#asset_classification_Type").each(function () {
             var textValue = $(this).val
             if (textValue == 'Low') {
                 $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
                             } 
         });
     });

 </script>

Comment: What you want this while entering data or while listing your data?

Comment: Based on condition i.e., if Type ="low" then the entire row should be in red color, I am using ruby-on-rails..where sould i write "java script"???

Comment: I am asking where you want to change color when user enter critical value while adding in you system or when you display data in table.

Comment: In table it should check condition for Type ,if it is true then row color change..

Comment: Then its so simple try it like this
<tr style="<%= 'color:red;' if obj.critical == 'low' %>">
<td><%= obj.name %></td><td><%= obj.xyz %></td>
</tr>

Comment: What is obj in your case (my table name is asset_classifications, fileds are Name, Type, Criteria, Value) it checks condition if Type = Low then row color change to red if it High the Green

Comment: obj is your single objects:
AssetClassification.all.each do |obj|
.......
end

Comment: Where should i add these piece of code.. I added in my .js file but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do can be easily achieved with jQuery.

```
$(function(){
    $("#field_in_your_table").keyup(function() {
      var textValue = $(this).val();
      if(textValue === "low"){
        // add css class or any manipulation to your dom.
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you say where should i post this piece of code..because am new to this JQuery and ruby dont mind

Comment: Sure. Rails generate javascript files for you when you create resources but they're in coffeescript. Just rename the .js.cofeescript file to .js and put it there. You'll need to wrap it with a dom ready function. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @sunilkalyan it usually has the same name as your model name. your_model_name.js.coffeescript

Comment: $(function(){
    $("Type").keyup(function() {
      var textValue = $(this).val();
      if(textValue === "low"){
     'background-color': green
        
      }
    });
}); is it correct??

Comment: Not really, $("Type") is not a valid selector. You have to select either using by id (#) or class (.) then for the css, You will have to add it like this $('#type').css('background-color','green');

Comment: It's not working!! Hassanin Ahmed, my field is "Type" in asset_classifications table

Comment: desc asset_classifications;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Type       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Criteria   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
               |
|
 this is my table!!!

Comment: @sunilkalyan yes but the name of the field in your form isn't Type. Use the developer tool on chrome or firebug to find out the id of the field.

Comment: right click on the textbox and click inspect element.

Comment: yep!! id : asset_classification_Type, where should i change sorry to trouble you

Comment: It's no problem. Instead of $("Type") change it to $("#asset_classification_Type").

Comment: $(function(){
    $("#asset_classification_Type").keyup(function() {
      var textValue = $(this).val();
      if(textValue == "Low"){
     $('#asset_classification_Type').css('background-color','Yellow'); 
        
      }
    });
});  changed not working !!!

Comment: Served asset /asset_classifications.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2014-02-12 13:13:31] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about html table, if so;  you can use jquery change() function to handle critical input fields changes.
Use val() function to control value, if it is "low" then add a css class to parent table row.
It is not about ruby, just jquery and html.

Comment: $(function(){
    $("#asset_classification_Type").keyup(function() {
      var textValue = $(this).val();
      if(textValue =="low"){
       $("#asset_classification_Type").css('background-color','Yellow');
      }
    });
});   its not working will you help?